# find number of rows without using count() in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can anybody help me to find way to count number of rows found while running query. I want to run this query in stored procedure depending on the count i want to perform certain actions.
I was trying to set variable value something like.

```
 Select abc_master_id,
        abc_name,
        abc_parent_id,
       (@row := @row +1)  rownum 
 from abc_master 
 where blah..  blah.. limit 18,9
```

Above query is completely wrong. But here I want to count or set some flag that records found are less than or equal to limit set to query i.e here 9. By doing this i will save one query for counting rows fetched by query.

I have tried using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and Found_rows() but it gives me total number of rows if query run without limit.

Answer (score 3):

The solution:

```
SELECT abc_master_id, 
       abc_name,
       abc_parent_id,
       @i:=@i+1 AS rownum 
FROM abc_master ,(SELECT @i:=0) foo
where blah.. blah.. limit 18,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query with a similar one

```
Select count(*)
from abc_master where blah.. blah..
```

and fetch the first row.

Mysql has improved over the years but I don't know if your engine supports the much simpler subquery:

```
select count(*) from (
Select abc_master_id, abc_name, abc_parent_id ... from abc_master
where blah.. blah..)
```

Thus: your original query but without the limit clause, between parens.